# How to display a image in div without resizing it

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I have a div of **160x160** pixels. I want to display image in this div. I want to show image in div without resizing it.

- If image is smaller than div then show the image in the center of the div without resizing.
- If image is bigger then div then show central part of the image in div without resizing it.

This div is like a window in real world. You can see view from that window according to size of window.

I think you can understand this?

Thanks

Comment: you can use background-clip property of css3 to clip the image or use clip property

Comment: hey, just noticed you didn't accept an answer for this. did you get the problem solved? :)

Answer (score 7):

Just use a simple background image like this:

```
div {background:url(image.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat; height:160px; width:160px}
```

If you want to use an actual `<img>` you could do this:

```
<div><img src="image.jpg" /></div>​​​​​​​​​​​​​

div {position:relative; text-align:center; overflow:hidden; height:160px; width:160px}
img {position:absolute; left:50%; margin-left:-250px}​
```

Where `margin-left` is half the image width - only works when you know the image size ahead of time. You could grab the image size and do this with JavaScript if you don't know it?

Comment: but what if he wants to use the image in some way, by referencing it?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean?

Comment: Then use the second way I have proposed, with the <img> tag - then it's an object in the page.

Comment: how do you know the image is 500px wide?

Comment: Again, I have addressed that in my answer, did you actually read it all? This isn't your question, are you trying to do the same thing?

Answer (score 3):

```
<div><img src="yourimage.jpg" /></div>

div{width:auto; margin:0 auto}
div img{max-width:100%}
```

max-width takes the max width as the original size of the image. Even ig you resize the window also you can see the effect with smaller image.

Comment: OP doesn't want to resize the image if its size is greater than that of div. setting max-width will eventually resize the image

Answer (score 1):

You can also set the image as background

```
background: url('image.png') no-repeat center center;
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/H5U3H/

Answer (score 1):

**I think this is what you need.....**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <style type="text/css">
            #imageLoader{
                border:1px solid #B0B0B0;
                height:160px;
                width:160px;
                background-image: url('images/Science.png');
                background-position:center center;
                background-repeat:no-repeat;
                background-clip:content-box;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="imageLoader" style="">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Change Image Names Accordingly...**

**Here is my** [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vijaysarin/BgKg9/1/)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to set the image as the background image of the div.

```
div { 
    background: transparent url(path/to/image.jpg) no-repeat center 0; 
    width: 160px; 
    height: 160px; 
}
```

That will center the image if it is bigger than the div, otherwise it will display the image in the (horizontal) center of the div.

Comment: This is not a good solution if you want to display it as a real image. Since a background behaves completely different in for example facebook. Images in the <img> tag are found as a possible thumbnail for your link, but a background is not. There are also other problems with crawlers such as Google. Also, when you have it as a true <img>, it is possible to add a alternate text for blind people. This is much more friendlier and thus better. Also, what if the css is not loaded? Then the image will not be displayed. A background is NOT an image.

Answer (score 0):

My take on this, you don't need to know the width of the image using transform / top / left:

```html
<div style=" overflow: hidden; width: 160px; height: 160px">
  <img src='https://images.pexels.com/photos/67636/rose-blue-flower-rose-blooms-67636.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500' style="position: relative; left: 50%; top: 50%; transform: translate(-50%, -50%)"/>
</div>
```